# Confusion over the navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to C#, as long as I know navigation property navigates using the `Include` extension method, I have two tables in the database, first one is:

```
[Key]
public int pc_group_id { get; set; }
public string pc_group_pattern { get; set; }
public string pc_group_name { get; set; }
```

And the second one is:

```
[Key]
public int m_error_id { get; set; }
public string m_error_name { get; set; }
public int m_event_type_id { get; set; }
public string m_inv_error_details { get; set; }
```

The above tables can be joined on two different names (`pc_group_pattern` , `m_inv_error_details`) but the same value, now I want to know if I can use the `Include` keyword, how can I get data from both tables? Can someone explain to me if I'm wrong in my understanding of `Include` definition and logic?

Comment: what is `m_inv_error_details`'s type?

Comment: @Outman edited,its string

Comment: Navigation properties are (virtual) fields in your classes used for referentiation. E.g.: `public class MyClassA { public virtual MyClassB MyClassB { get; set; } }`. You did not post any navigation properties above, though.
`Include` can be used for applications without lazy loading. Query a parent, get a parent. Query a parent.Include(p => p.Childs), get a parent and it's childs.
This is only one use-case, cant explain everything in max. 600 characters =) Hope it helps you anyway! Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string is not "navigable".
so if you want to share a string value between entities you have to "encapsulate" it in a class:

```
public class CA {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public CC C {get; set; }
    public ICollection<CB> Bs {get; set;}
}

public class CC {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int AId {get; set;}
    public virtual CA A {get; set;}

    public string V {get; set;}
}    

public class CB {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int AId {get; set;}
    public virtual CA A {get; set;}

    public string V {get; set;}
}
```

In this sample the navigations properties are:

- C, Bs
- CC.A
- CB.A

This is not a all exhaustive. I just try to illustrate "navigation properties".